# Connecting a picture box being pressed to a certain letter

Tags: c#, winforms

I have questions in my program that are jumbled up words and the user tries to un-jumble them. I want them to do this by them clicking multiple picture which have certain letters on it to form the word but I don't know how to connect the picture I have to a certain letter (e.g. Say I have a picture of the letter "a" how do I connect it so that the program knows when that picture is pressed the letter a is pressed).

This is the coding I have so far (to randomize the question and link the answers to it).

*Also I'm very new to coding so any suggestions please can you show what exactly to add/change to my code.

```
public partial class Level1 : Form
{
    Random rnd = new Random(); //sets the random variable 
    List<string> strStrings = new List<string>() { "ZUZB", "HXAO", "MXAE", "KYCU", "CWEH", "PHIC", "HOCP", "SXIA", "ISHF", "KOJE" };//displays wprds om a list
    Dictionary<string, string> dictStrings = new Dictionary<string, string>() //dictionary containing the word as the key, and the answer as the value in the key/value pair.
    {
        { "ZUZB", "BUZZ" },
        { "HXAO", "HOAX" },
        { "MXAE", "EXAM" },
        { "KYCU", "YUCK" },
        { "CWEH", "CHEW" },
        { "PHIC", "CHIP" },
        { "HOCP", "CHOP" },
        { "SXIA", "AXIS" },
        { "ISHF", "FISH" },
        {"KOJE", "JOKE"  }
    };

    public Level1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int skip; //declares the skip  variable
    int score; //declares the score variable
    int question; //decalres the question variable 

    private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (strStrings.Count > 0)
        {
            string rndWord = strStrings[rnd.Next(0, strStrings.Count())];

            lbljumble.Text = rndWord;
            strStrings.Remove(rndWord);
        }
        else
        {
            lbljumble.Text = "No more questions!";
        }

        answerLabel.Text = ""; //randomly displays questions in the label until there are no more questions left to ask

        score += 10; //add 10 to score and display in label
        lblscore.Text = Convert.ToString(score);


        question += 1; //add one to question number and display in label
        lblqnum.Text = Convert.ToString(question);
        tmrtime.Interval = (tmrtime.Interval) - 100; //amount of time taken after each question
    }

    private void answerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string answer = (dictStrings.TryGetValue(lbljumble.Text, out answer)) ? answer : "";
        answerLabel.Text = answer; //displays answer in label after the answer button is pressed to display the corresponding answer to the question
    }

    private void btnskip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        skip = 1; //skip equals 1
        if (skip == 1) //of skip equals one 
        {
            skip--; //take one from skip
            lblskip.Text = " remaining: no"; //display that no skips are available

        }
        else
        {
            lblskip.Text = "No skips remaining"; //display no skips remaining 
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some picture-boxes and name them as `Letter_a_pb`, `Letter_b_pb` etc., create a `Click` event, and then create an `if` statement to check which `pictureBox` is clicked and if it equal to the letter 'a'.

For instance:

```
string question = "a";
private void Letter_a_pb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (question == "a")
        MessageBox.Show("Excellent!");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Try Again!");
}
```

Let me know if this is what you've searched for.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you would like to know what letter was selected/clicked by the user.

You can dynamically create picture boxes, assign the `.Name` of the picture box to the value you would like the picture box to have then subscribe to the `Click` event for each picture box.

In the click event check the name of the sending picture box *`object sender`*. (you could alternatively use the `pictureBx.Tag` if you don't want to use the `pictureBx.Name` )

Here is an example form.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         lblAnswer.Text = "";            
         DrawLeters();
     }

     string checkAnswer = "check";
     void DrawLeters()
     {
         this.SuspendLayout();
         string[] alphabet = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z".Split(",");

         var pictureLocation = new Point(0, 0);
         for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Length; i++)
         {
             //Create a picture box
             PictureBox pictureBx = new PictureBox();
             //set the default location of the box (0,0) in this scenario
             pictureBx.Location = pictureLocation;
             //make the box 16 by 16
             pictureBx.Size = new Size(16, 16);
             //set the name of the box to that of the letter it represents
             pictureBx.Name = alphabet[i];
             //assign a click event to the box
             pictureBx.Click += PictureBx_Click;
             //now create the image that will fill the box
             Image img = new Bitmap(16, 16);
             using (Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(img))
             {
                 graph.Clear(Color.White);
                 Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                 graph.DrawString(pictureBx.Name, this.Font, textBrush, 0, 0);
                 graph.Save();
             }
             //assign the image to the box
             pictureBx.Image = img;

             //add the box to the form
             this.Controls.Add(pictureBx);

             //change the location for the next box
             pictureLocation.X += 17;
             if (i % 10 == 0 && i > 0)
             {
                 pictureLocation.Y += 17;
                 pictureLocation.X = 0;
             }
         }
         this.ResumeLayout(false);
         this.PerformLayout();
     }        

     private void PictureBx_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {   // assign the clicked value to the answer label
         if (sender is PictureBox pbx)
             lblAnswer.Text += pbx.Name;
     }       

     private void checkAnswerBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         //check the answer
         if (lblAnswer.Text == checkAnswer)
             lblFeedback.Text = "Correct!!";
         else
             lblFeedback.Text = "NO!!";
     }

     private void clearBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         //clear the answer label
         lblAnswer.Text = "";
     }
 }
```

and the result is this.
*i'm just checking that the answer is `check` you would use your own logic to determine the correct answer.*

[image]